# Designing XAML files on a Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xaml

I am putting together an application using WPF. A designer would like to work on the look of some of the windows using a Mac.

Does anyone know if its possible edit the actual XAML file that the programme will use on a Mac? It would help a great deal.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no way to test since I haven't had a mac in quite some time, but I would think a Windows emulator and a lightweight editor like [kxaml](http://www.kxaml.com) may do it. However design wise it's also worth mention there's a [xaml export plugin](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) available for mac Adobe Illustrator from Mike Swanson (very, very handy to a designer) that would allow him to export his designs to XAML he could use to make visual assets you could drop right in relatively painlessly.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) is a good editor that includes syntax highlighting for many formats including XAML.

Version 3 includes installers for OS X (10.7 or later), Windows, and Ubuntu. (tarballs are available for other flavors of Unix.)